# Bottleneck on Data Source

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We work with DataFlow jobs (batch) processing data from BigQuery. The size of the source is about 60M rows, with a total size of 300GB. That grows linearly every day by 2M.

We have a timestamp, but we aggregate our records across time, the timestamp is not used during the processing. Reading takes 10+ hours for now.

The bottleneck of the job seems to be the reading and transfer of all this data. Everything happening during the processing is scaled among multiple machines, this is ok at scale.

I know it is possible to deal with Terabytes or Petabytes of data, how can it be done at the reading step?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your pipeline? Is it a streaming pipeline? What makes you feel like you have a bottleneck? Is your watermark getting stuck? Or is this batch?
Also, if you have a job id, we can take a look at the pipeline directly.

Comment: It is batch processing. The reading itself is 10+ hours. I have to check for other steps happening after, but reading determines the min boundary in time, so I can easily imagine very soon 24+ hours. Unless the reading speed is reduced because a bottleneck is detected further in the Pipeline.

Comment: Could you share a job ID so we can look at what is happening? Are you using the standard BigQuery source? Which version of the SDK?

Comment: Thanks @BenChambers and Pablo, this is an example of a job ID: 2017-08-14_20_43_07-1678694545934366057. The SDK is "Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Python 2.0.0"

Comment: Also, this job is reading right now and seems to be struggling on the reading: 2017-08-25_14_11_08-3810392151442847676

Comment: Seems like the workers are processing the results of the BigQuery export at about 2 megabytes per second per worker (with 15 workers), which likely could be improved but seems not entirely unreasonable - BigQuery exports to Avro files, and the Python Avro library is unfortunately quite slow. Is it an option to simply use more workers?

Comment: Meanwhile filed JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2810

Comment: Thanks @jkff. Yes we can use more workers for now, I am just worried to have the reading of BQ being the bottleneck, because we can't really do anything to improve it in the future and scale up. Also the volume of data we have seems really small compared to some other existing applications, it seemed weird to us to have BQ+Beam+DataFlow struggling on our problems.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use Beam Java instead of Beam Python, if performance is very important?

Comment: We could us Beam Java but it would be the only piece of code not in Python in our codebase. From a general point of view, Beam Python seems to have a lot to catch up on Beam Java both in features and perf. Do you know if Apache will keep going to develop them independently or do they want to close the gap? And if the issue you created on Jira is solved, how long does a cycle generally take for Beam, to push a new version with a new improvement like that? Out of curiosity